# Static Variable and textbox between 2 forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I got this idea of using a static variable to transfer data between two forms using MSVS 2010.

I am having problems right now with the way it is working. Form2 is my main user interaction screen where items are scanned and displayed to a textbox. When I use Form4 I want to be able to subtract an item and display that discription in the textbox on Form2 without erasing the previous data that was on the screen of Form2.

Here is an example code of what I am using in form4:

```
        else if (input_txtBox.Text == "E007C02A55EF937C")
        {
            secondForm.textBox2.Text = "Snickers Bar.................-$0.99" + Environment.NewLine;
            input_txtBox.Text = ""; // clears textBox1
            input_txtBox.Text = "";
            Form2.Subtotal = Form2.Subtotal - Form2.Candy_Bar;
            Form2.Tax = Form2.Candy_Bar * Form2.Taxrate - Form2.Tax;
```

This is after the button click:

```
        Form2.Total = Form2.Subtotal + Form2.Tax;
        secondForm.textBox3.Text = Form2.Subtotal.ToString("#0.00");
        secondForm.textBox4.Text = Form2.Tax.ToString("#0.00");
        secondForm.textBox5.Text = Form2.Total.ToString("#0.00");
```

The variables being used in Form4 are declared in Form2 as a public static decimal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok I think I found the problem that I am having. When I leave Form2 it is hiding it and erasing the data so when Form4 is closed it just adds the data to the textbox from Form2. Is there a way to save all data to a string in a textbox and recall it?

Answer (score 2):

> I got this idea of using a static variable to transfer data between two forms using MSVS 2010.

Why? It sounds like either `Form2` or `Form4` (both of which should be given *real* names which indicate their purpose) should have a reference to the other - or alternatively, both should have a reference to a common data model which is responsible for transferring data appropriately.

Using a static field as a way of avoiding proper OO design is definitely a bad idea - it'll save you time in the short term, but lead to code which is hard to follow, hard to test, and screws up as soon as you think that maybe you want *two* instances of Form2, each assoicated with an instance of Form4...

Comment: I am new to C# and teaching myself so this was one of the way I found to get to work so far except for the textbox data being erased.

Comment: @ajaustin12: Teach yourself good object oriented practices early on, so you don't slip into bad habits. Static variables are *often* a design smell. Not always, but often. Look into the various OO designs for UIs, particularly MVVM if yuo're able to use WPF or Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far better to run a separate background thread which acts as a control for the forms, with this you could use the thread running in the background to keep control of all your variables and open forms as you need to.

You'll need to set up delegate methods to allow safe access between the thread and the forms, but it would be much more efficient and easier than the way you are suggesting.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It would help if I was more experienced with C#. Unfortunately I am teaching myself so I am not familiar with how to do that.

Comment: A great option would be to take a look at the Yellow Book to help teach yourself C#. http://www.robmiles.com/c-yellow-book/